# Adding / removing elements from the DOM and it's effect on performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a project that involves displaying a table of records to a user. Each record has the potential to display multiple embedded youtube videos.
Initially I loaded all of the embedded iframes and just did a show/hide depending on the active record. This was obviously horrendous for performance.

My current solution is to load a placeholder image, and then inject the iframe into the dom when the user clicks on the image. This works great for the first load, however if a user loads a second record, and has to load in a second iframe, the performance starts to suffer.

I've tried removing the element from the dom using

```
$('iframe').remove();
```

however this doesn't seem to offer any performance benefit. Is there a way of removing the previous iframe when clicking on a new record, that will perform efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested this with 5 iframes or with 30000 iframes? If it's 5 you won't notice any perfomance improvements on any solution.

Comment: I tested this with a couple of iframes. Sadly the performance degradation is noticable with that few. I thought if I could remove it from the DOM it'd speed up performance but it seems it stays in memory and causes slowdown...